# Define path of image location

Tags: macros, urls

I am trying to set a variable with a file location but I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\Url Error ->\url used in a moving argument. 

l.166 ...epaspectratio]{\MOFile}
```

In my tex file I have:

```
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{soul}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,filecolor=green,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %Type1-font for non-english texts and characters
\usepackage{graphicx} %%For loading graphic files
\usepackage{subfig} %%Subfigures inside a figure
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{slashbox,pict2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{changepage}

\input{Variables}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{0cm}{0cm}
    \tableofcontents %Table of contents
    \pagestyle{plain} 
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \chapter{Info}
        \section{Timestep}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=11cm, keepaspectratio]{\MOFile}
                \caption{Histogram}
            \end{figure}

        \FloatBarrier   
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

In Variables.tex:

```
\def \MOFile{\path{C:\Users\y\Documents\temp_20171010120402\timestep.png}}
```

I've found some information on this issue but can't get it solved. I thought putting \protect in front of \path would solve it but it doesn't. Also changing \path to \url doesn't help.

How would I solve this?

**Edit 1:**
I changed the backslash in the path to a forward slash, but still get an error:

```
\Url Error ->\url used in a moving argument. 

l.166 ...epaspectratio]{\MOFile}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Use of \protect doesn't match its definition.
\filename@base ...t \edef lmr{lmtt}\protect \xdef 
                                              \T1/lmr/m/n/10 {\T1/lmr/m/...
l.166 ...epaspectratio]{\MOFile}

If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.
```

The changed path is defined as:

```
\def \MOFile{\path{C:/Users/y/Documents/temp_20171010122638/timestep.png}}
```

Comment: You can't the way you try it. The `url` package evaluates its argument in a verbatim way which can't be used in the definition of other macros. `expl3`/LaTeX3 offers a way to store verbatim like input into a variable.

Comment: your path is wrong you should use `/` not `\ ` for tex paths, even on windows.

Comment: I have changed it, but still get errors (see editted post)

Comment: oh you can't do `\includegraphics[width=11cm, keepaspectratio]{\MOFile}`  as you can't do `\includegraphics{\path{a/b.png}}` the syntax is `\includegraphics{/a/b.png}` with no `\path`.

Comment: Don't use \path in the definition. Only `\def \MOFile{C:/Users/y/Documents/temp_20171010120402/timestep.png}`. (Side remark: it would be better to avoid absolute pathes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path is wrong you should use `/` not `\` for tex paths, even on windows.

and can't do

```
\includegraphics[width=11cm, keepaspectratio]{\MOFile}
```

as you can't do `\includegraphics{\path{a/b.png}}` the syntax is `\includegraphics{/a/b.png}` with no `\path`.

So use the path directly, or do not use `\path` in the definition of `\MOfile`

But your document would be more portable if you just used

```
\includegraphics{timestep}
```

the `.png` extension will be defaulted and the file will be found as long as it is anywhere in TeX's input path.